# Recursively list through directory and exclude certain files and subdirs

Tags: powershell, 7zip

I am trying to recursively traverse through a directory, then ignore certain files and sub-folders before zipping the contents of that directory (preserving the directory structure).

**Here is the directory structure:**

[image]

Here is powershell script:

I have updated my code:

```
[zipParams()]
param(
    [String]$dir,
    [String]$Zipfile
)

function create-zip
{
    [zipParams()]
    param(
        [String]$dir,
        [String]$Zipfile
    )

    "$dir, $Zipfile"

    echo $dir;
    [String]$pathZipExe = "C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe";
    [Array]$arguments = "a", "-tzip", "$Zipfile", "$dir", "-xr!obj", "-xr!Forms\*.aspx.cs", "-xr!Forms\*.aspx.designer.cs", "-xr!Forms\*.aspx.resx", "-xr!UserControls\*.ascx.cs", "-xr!UserControls\*.ascx.designer.cs", "-xr!UserControls\*.ascx.resx", "-xr!Reports\*.aspx.cs", "-xr!Reports\*.aspx.resx";
    & $pathZipExe $arguments;
}

create-zip -dir $dir -Zipfile $Zipfile
```

I am executing the powershell script with the below command.

```
powershell -Command "& {"C:\MyCave\iso\SDG\zipps.ps1" -dir """C:\MyCave\iso\SDG\powershellcmp""" -Zipfile """C:\MyCave\iso\SDG\powershellcmp\cmp-$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd)
.zip"""}"
```

It is zipping but it is not excluding files and certain folders (extensions highlighted in the code).

Where am I making a mistake? Please guide. This is my first try at PS scripting...

Comment: **1.** You never  invoke the `create-zip` function from inside the `zipfile.ps1` script. **2** Use  `powershell -Command "& {"C:\Users\Kris\Desktop\zipfile.ps1" -dir """C:\MyCave\iso\SDG\powershellcmp""" -Zipfile """C:\MyCave\iso\SDG\powershellcmp\cmp-$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).zip"""}"` (read `powershell -?` for `-Command` parameter form: _To write a string that runs a Windows PowerShell command, use the format: `"& {<command>}"`_),

Comment: Hi @JosefZ ..invoke the function from inside PS script. Should it be placed below the method like **create-zip**? But how would I place parameters and their values alongside function name because I am passing two params to the function.

Comment: You can simply omit all the `function` keyword and curly braces surrounding the function body, and add `param` statement. Read [_about_scripts_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-5.1) help topic.

Comment: @JosefZ I have omitted function & {}. I am getting an error while executing the program...**The term 'C:\Users\Kris' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.**

Comment: Does it work, if you run the .ps1 from a different location? Like C:\MyCave\Script..

Comment: @DanStef the code is working, but it is not excluding files and folders not meant to be zipped.

Comment: @JosefZ Please see the progress...Need some more guidance

Comment: Remove `[zipParams()]` (both occurrences).

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the source of your problem, but the following script should work

```
function my-zip
{
    param(
        [string]$archive,
        [string]$myBase
    )
    $zipExe = Join-Path $env:ProgramFiles '7-zip\7z.exe'
    if(-not(Test-Path $zipExe))
    {
        $zipExe = Join-Path ${env:ProgramFiles(x86)} '7-zip\7z.exe'
        if(-not(Test-Path $zipExe))
        {
            Write-Host "7-Zip.exe not found" -ForegroundColor Red
            throw "7-Zip.exe not found"
            return 1
        }
    }

    $zipOutput = &$zipExe a -tzip $archive $myBase\* -r '-xr!*.prod' '-xr!*.test' '-xr!*.exe'
    # &$zipExe a -tzip $archive $myBase\* -r '-xr!*.prod' '-xr!*.test' '-xr!*.exe'
    if ($zipOutput -contains 'Everything is OK')
    {
        Write-Host "Files in directory $myBase added" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Problem during archiving files in $myBase" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}

my-zip -archive c:\temp\test\test2019-1.zip -myBase C:\temp\test
```

Update:
-r (Recurse subdirectories) switch
Specifies the method of treating wildcards and filenames on the command line.

Syntax
-r[- | 0]
Switch  Description
-r  Enable recurse subdirectories.
-r- Disable recurse subdirectories. This option is default for all commands.
-r0 Enable recurse subdirectories only for wildcard names.
Examples
7z l archive.zip *.doc -r-
lists all *.doc files that belong to the archived root directory in the archive.zip archive.

7z a -tzip archive.zip -r src*.cpp src*.h
adds all *.cpp and *.h files from directory src and all it's subdirectories to the archive.zip archive.

Found here:
https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/recurse.htm

Comment: Is $myBase\* -r a recursive traversal through directories?

Comment: Yes, from my understanding thats how it works.. Have a look here: https://superuser.com/questions/185135/add-to-a-7-zip-archive-how-to-exclude-certain-file-types-extensions